# Getting error with httpclient5 with HTTP2 & SSL (java.io.IOException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host)

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, apache-httpcomponents, apache-httpasyncclient, apache-httpclient-5.x

I am writing a client using HttpClient 5.0 beta to request/load a secure URL/resource in Tomcat which supports HTTP2.
The program is as below. It is taken from Apache httpclient 5 examples (the code is exactly same except the way the SSL context is created with loadTrustMaterial)

```
public class Http2TlsAlpnRequestExecutionExample {

    public final static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {
        String trustStorePath = "C:\\cert\\keystore.jks";
        String trustStorePassword = "password";         
        SSLContext sslContext = SSLContexts.custom().loadTrustMaterial(new File(trustStorePath), trustStorePassword.toCharArray()).build();

        // Create and start requester
        H2Config h2Config = H2Config.custom()
                .setPushEnabled(false)
                .build();

        final HttpAsyncRequester requester = H2RequesterBootstrap.bootstrap().setVersionPolicy(HttpVersionPolicy.FORCE_HTTP_2)
                .setH2Config(h2Config)
                .setTlsStrategy(new H2ClientTlsStrategy(sslContext, new SSLSessionVerifier() {

                    public TlsDetails verify(final NamedEndpoint endpoint, final SSLEngine sslEngine) throws SSLException {
                        return null;
                    }

                }))
                .setStreamListener(new Http2StreamListener() {

                    public void onHeaderInput(final HttpConnection connection, final int streamId, final List<? extends Header> headers) {
                        for (int i = 0; i < headers.size(); i++) {
                            System.out.println(connection + " (" + streamId + ") << " + headers.get(i));
                        }
                    }

                    public void onHeaderOutput(final HttpConnection connection, final int streamId, final List<? extends Header> headers) {
                        for (int i = 0; i < headers.size(); i++) {
                            System.out.println(connection + " (" + streamId + ") >> " + headers.get(i));
                        }
                    }

                    public void onFrameInput(final HttpConnection connection, final int streamId, final RawFrame frame) {
                    }


                    public void onFrameOutput(final HttpConnection connection, final int streamId, final RawFrame frame) {
                    }

                    public void onInputFlowControl(final HttpConnection connection, final int streamId, final int delta, final int actualSize) {
                    }

                    public void onOutputFlowControl(final HttpConnection connection, final int streamId, final int delta, final int actualSize) {
                    }

                })
                .create();
        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("HTTP requester shutting down");
                requester.shutdown(ShutdownType.GRACEFUL);
            }
        });
        requester.start();

        HttpHost target = new HttpHost("localhost", 1090, "https");
        String[] requestUris = new String[] {"/rest/rest/helloWorld"};

        final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(requestUris.length);
        for (final String requestUri: requestUris) {
            final Future<AsyncClientEndpoint> future = requester.connect(target, Timeout.ofSeconds(5));
            final AsyncClientEndpoint clientEndpoint = future.get();
            clientEndpoint.execute(
                    new BasicRequestProducer("GET", target, requestUri),
                    new BasicResponseConsumer<String>(new StringAsyncEntityConsumer()),
                    new FutureCallback<Message<HttpResponse, String>>() {


                        public void completed(final Message<HttpResponse, String> message) {
                            clientEndpoint.releaseAndReuse();
                            HttpResponse response = message.getHead();
                            String body = message.getBody();
                            System.out.println(requestUri + "->" + response.getCode() + " " + response.getVersion());
                            System.out.println(body);
                            latch.countDown();
                        }


                        public void failed(final Exception ex) {
                            clientEndpoint.releaseAndDiscard();
                            System.out.println(requestUri + "->" + ex);
                            ex.printStackTrace();
                            latch.countDown();
                        }


                        public void cancelled() {
                            clientEndpoint.releaseAndDiscard();
                            System.out.println(requestUri + " cancelled");
                            latch.countDown();
                        }

                    });
        }

        latch.await();
        System.out.println("Shutting down I/O reactor");
        requester.initiateShutdown();
    }

}
```

I get following exception when I run the code.

```
java.io.IOException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read0(Native Method)
at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:43)
at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:223)
at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:197)
at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:380)
at org.apache.hc.core5.reactor.ssl.SSLIOSession.receiveEncryptedData(SSLIOSession.java:443)
at org.apache.hc.core5.reactor.ssl.SSLIOSession.isAppInputReady(SSLIOSession.java:498)
at org.apache.hc.core5.reactor.InternalDataChannel.onIOEvent(InternalDataChannel.java:112)
at org.apache.hc.core5.reactor.InternalChannel.handleIOEvent(InternalChannel.java:50)
at org.apache.hc.core5.reactor.SingleCoreIOReactor.processEvents(SingleCoreIOReactor.java:173)
at org.apache.hc.core5.reactor.SingleCoreIOReactor.doExecute(SingleCoreIOReactor.java:123)
at org.apache.hc.core5.reactor.AbstractSingleCoreIOReactor.execute(AbstractSingleCoreIOReactor.java:80)
at org.apache.hc.core5.reactor.IOReactorWorker.run(IOReactorWorker.java:44)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

If I do not set set version policy as HttpVersionPolicy.FORCE_HTTP_2  on H2RequesterBootstrap, it works but in that case it uses HTTP/1.1. But I have to use HTTP2 only.

Just to check, I tried it with Jetty's HTTP2 client and it worked. But I have to use Apache HttpClient 5.0 only.

Could you help, please? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think the server you're trying to connect is not http2 enabled, you need to configure your webapp to accept http2 requests. If you're using apache tomcat, you need tomcat 9.x with JDK9 or above to support http2. [Check here](https://readlearncode.com/configure-tomcat-9-for-http2/) to configure http2 for apache tomcat. You also need to install openssl and apr libraries which supports http2.

Follow this [link](https://jmchung.github.io/blog/2013/09/06/centos-installing-apache-portable-runtime-apr-for-tomcat/) for installing apr and openssl libraries

Comment: you don't need JDK9 or above, also works with Java8